# Check string with Parsley.js custom validator

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I want to check if textarea contains  a link. It doesn't need to be anything complicated, just checking for `http` or `www` is good enough for me.

But this doesn't work and I don't get anything with `console.log();`
How can I debug Parsley validator?

I just want to check if value doesn't contain http then return true for validation pass.

```
    window.Parsley.addValidator('messageWithoutLink', {
        validateNumber: function(value, requirement) {
            console.log(value);
            if(value.indexOf("http") !== -1)
                return value;
            else 
                return false;
        },
        requirementType: 'string',
        messages: {
            en: 'No links allowed'
        }
    });

<textarea id="contact_message" name="message" required data-parsley-required-message="Obligatory message" data-parsley-message-without-link></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `validateString`, not `validateNumber`